# Why AUCTeX/pdflatex show me help in Japanese?

Tags: auctex, error-handling

I had this error message displayed to me by AUCTeX (already corrected using `\ddot{\boldsymbol x}`)

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten $.

--- TeX said ---
<recently read> }

l.51 \[ \boldsymbol M\ddot\boldsymbol
                                      x + \boldsymbol K\boldsymbol x =
--- HELP ---
括弧または数式モードのデリミタが正しく対応していません．おそらく{・\[・
\(あるいは$のうちのいずれかを書き忘れたのでしょう．
```

Google's Translate says it's Japanese...

In the `*scratch*` buffer I have

```
(getenv "LANG")
"C.UTF-8"
```

I'm on Debian Sid with an updated Debian TeXLive and `auctex-12.1.2` installed with `elpa`

What's going on?

---

**Addendum**

I had consistently the help message in Japanese using either `pdflatex` or `xelatex` or `luatex` while from the shell I had, in all cases, the help message in English.  Both in Emacs and the shell I have `LANG` set to `C.UTF-8`.

The problem was *solved* (so to say) restarting Emacs.  In a new copy of Emacs, with a new instance of AUCTeX I have again the help messages in English.

The strange behaviour I experienced is likely due to a casual interaction between the user and Emacs/AUCTeX and I don't expect that we can find what happened, on the other hand I don't want to remove the question but it's fine if you close it.

Comment: What is the documentclass of your tex file?

Comment: @FranBurstall `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`

Comment: Is your locale the same outside of Emacs? Try spawning a shell in a terminal outside of Emacs and looking at `LANG` inside of it.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 My locale is `C.UTF-8` in the shell and in the X session.  Emacs was started from the window manager that, in turn, was started by my `~/.Xsession` (I know, very old fashonied, isn't it?). I add that I don't see Japanese very often, not at all...

Comment: What happens if you run latex, eg `pdflatex file.tex`, on the file outside emacs in a shell?

Comment: @FranBurstall Outside Emacs I have help ("H" after the processor stops on error) in English, when I run the same file from Emacs/AUCTeX I consistently have the help message in Japanese. I have already verified that Emacs has the same `LANG` environment variable value. This happens when I use either `pdflatex` or  `xelatex` or `lualatex`.  Looks like something AUCTeX is doing behind my back... (I know, probably is something **I** had done )

Comment: I started a new Emacs issue and now help is in English... It is something that happened between me, Emacs and AUCTeX that doesn't seem contagious.  It's very difficult to debug an issue of this type...  I will edit my question to reflect this comment so that a possible new user with the same or similar issue knows at least the solution, even if the reason why remains obscure...

Comment: I can verify that I have the same problem.  When I encounter the Japanese, I just restart the Emacs session to get the English.  That is the only solution I have for now.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force search over the AUCTeX documentation points me to this [node](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Japanese.html), of which the last paragraph says the following.

> See ‘tex-jp.el’ for more information.

Then I look at the source of `tex-jp.el` and find the following lines.

```lisp
(defcustom japanese-TeX-error-messages t
  "*If non-nil, explain TeX error messages in Japanese."
  :group 'AUCTeX-jp
  :type 'boolean)

...

(if japanese-TeX-error-messages
(setq TeX-error-description-list
  '(("\\(?:Package Preview Error\\|Preview\\):.*" .
"`preview'へ`auctex'オプションを直接与えるのは避けてください．
プレビューの実行時以外でこのエラーが出た場合，余りにこみいったことを
しすぎか，でなければAUCTeXがひどい失敗をしています．")

...)
```

We should probably set the variable `japanese-TeX-error-messages` to `nil` in the init file or using the Easy Customization Interface.  Restart Emacs now and Japanese shall never appear again now.

We should probably file an issue to the AUCTeX maintainer and this option should be set to `nil` by default instead of `t`.